# WPF : Error on Initialize component (Test Machine)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I created a software which has a Administrator and user login which on successful login takes it to their respective XAML pages.  This works fine from code and installer on the machine where i created the software.

Now on deploying this on a test machine the app crashes in the **Initialize component** of the Admin page (Identiifed with debug mesages). The error report gives me this

```
  Problem Event Name: CLR20r3
  Problem Signature 01: gage selector.exe
  Problem Signature 02: 1.0.0.0
  Problem Signature 03: 52cd1461
  Problem Signature 04: mscorlib
  Problem Signature 05: 4.0.0.0
  Problem Signature 06: 4e181ae3
  Problem Signature 07: 3fd1
  Problem Signature 08: 105
  Problem Signature 09: System.Windows.Markup.XamlParse
  OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
  Locale ID: 1033
  Additional Information 1: 0a9e
  Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Additional Information 3: 0a9e
  Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
```

I am not able to figure out what is happening especially so since Operator xaml page loads fine in the test machine as well. Please guide on how to proceed in this case.

Comment: There is a problem with the XAML. For example missing files (because the image is not accessible on your production system. You could provide us with the XAML, that makes helping a lot easier.

Comment: @PatrickHofman : Yes Thanks. Should have cross checked that. I will do so and share if i am unable to find an issue with path not accessible.

Comment: Do you get an error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AS Patrick Hoffman pointed out this is a minor issue when some paths are inaccessible on XAML page. In my case i had not updated the dynamic path for the logo  on Admin page while i had done for other pages. Changing it to dynamic path fixed the issue.